# Will Juju support start/stop of existing units?

Tags: juju, cloud

Currently it seems that Juju is not able to start / stop existing units. Say I have a very large application that takes some time to push up a new machine, I would likely want to scale up machines in advance and then only bring them up when needed.

Currently add-unit adds new units. Is it likely juju will be extended to allow to provision units in advance and then when scaling up, use those units instead of creating totally new servers?

Cloud servers often cost money when running - thus it seems that this would make sense to be able to just stop/start instead of only add/remove.

Comment: I would imagine that this functionality is highly dependant on the cloud provider but please file a feature request https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+filebug so that it's on their radar.

Comment: Well afaik all cloud providers that have an API normally have start/stop operations - but yeah you're right, the best thing is to raise a feature :)

Comment: For anyone looking here - the bug is raised here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1252781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a super-interesting question. Yes, I think it would be a valuable addition to Juju, and would encourage you or others to work up a patch. As someone said, the underlying cloud infrastructure would need to support this operation, but even MAAS could turn physical machines on and off without releasing them.

Inviting a patch doesn't mean it would land but I think it's interesting enough to mock up the CLI and API extensions needed, and perhaps work up a prototype just for EC2 showing what's needed in core and in the provider.