# Is it possible to "stop" a particular unit in juju?

Tags: juju

I need to "stop" a unit in juju. Remove or destroy are not good options for my case, is there any way for "stop"ing a unit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/378920/will-juju-support-start-stop-of-existing-unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't currently be done from Juju itself, but you can go to the cloud provider's console and stop the instance that way.  You just need to run juju status, which will give you the instance ID, and then you can go to the cloud provider and stop the instance manually.